# GPO or Login script

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, login-script

i am unsure of what i should use.  i have a site with about 40 users and 6 different departments which need access to different areas and differnt mapped drives. What is better for me to create a group policy or a login script all users will be on windows 7 professional not sure if that makes much of a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're talking about selectively making "mapped" "drives" available for users depending on their group membership. (Obviously, actually controlling access to the resources is best done with NTFS ACLs.) For the "drives", [Group Policy Preferences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731892(v=ws.10).aspx) is probably your best bet. The user interface is much better than writing scripts and it's fully "supported" out of the box in Windows 7. You can use the [item-level targeting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733022.aspx) functionality to restrict application of a setting to members of a specific group.

Edit:

Group Policy Preferences is a mechanism to allow a variety of user environment settings to be controlled in a very granular way, via a GUI interface. These settings are stored within Group Policy Objects (GPOs) in the Active Directory, and are administered from the Group Policy Editor. The GPOs themselves are created and linked using the Group Policy Management console (on "modern" versions of Windows Server).

Comment: prob stupid question is GPO same as Group policy preferences

Comment: yes i was refering to mapped drives